# Button is not getting enabled?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

When the rewarded ad has done loading, `mButton` is supposed to get enabled.
But, the button gets enabled only when the current activity is `MainActivity`.

For example, if the video has loaded when the current activity is `AnotherActivity`, the button does not get enabled!

Code in `MainActivity` java class:

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    mButton.setEnabled(true); //works only in the MainActivity activity
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.me.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I enable `mButton` when the video has done loading while I'm in `AnotherActivity`?

Comment: @Yupi Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the button enable code in both the places - in onResume() and in onRewardedVideoAdLoaded().

```
private long mTimeRemaining;
private Button mTestButton;
private static boolean sEnable;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mTestButton.setEnabled(sEnable);
    ....
}

 ...

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    sEnable = true;
    mTestButton.setEnabled(sEnable);

}
```

Comment: I found the problem. I didn't add `static` to the boolean. Just out of curiosity what does static do?

Comment: `static` means - a) Only one copy of this variable for all the class objects. and b) its value is retained through multiple invocations.

More about `static` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: In what way did `static` solve my issue? I don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: :) Try running your app in debug mode with and without `static` modifier. Add breakpoints in the `onResume()` method where the variable is accessed and check its state in both the cases. You will see, that without `static`, when the `onResume()` is invoked, the variable is reset to default state i.e.`false` in case of  `boolean.`

Answer (score 1):

That's because you can not update UI when the respective Activity is not visible. You can maintain a flag when `onRewardedVideoAdLoaded()` is getting executed, and then check the flag to enable/disable the button when `MainActivity` is brought foreground.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please give code example?

Comment: I can give you pseudocode:
in MainActivity
- Static member variable - boolean enableButton; 
- update this variable in onRewardedVideoAdLoaded()
- check for its state in onResume()
- if true, enable button. disable otherwise.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't change anything... Please test your code :) I'm using Google AdMob to load ads.

Comment: LOL! I did test my code and it works :).
Ofcourse, the static variable will be reset when you exit the application. In that case  you can use SharedPreferences. But if you are looking for something that works while application running, this logic works.

Comment: if you are sure onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() gets executed even when MainActivity is not visible, the static logic, should work.

Comment: Did you try it with Google AdMobs?

Comment: You can test your logic with this project: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/RewardedVideoExample

Comment: I did test with above code. You will need to keep the button enable code in both the places. I have added the code in answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If your ad is loaded in some another `Activity` rather then in `MainActivity` then save your state for example use `sharedpreferences`. You could use values like: 1 if ad is loaded and 0 if not and do something like this:

If video is loaded:

```
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().
                                putInt("value", 1).apply(); // word value is key
```

Then override `onResume` and `onStart` in your `MainActivity` and inside check is video loaded by getting the value from `SharedPreferences` like this:

```
 int i = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).
                            getInt("value", 0).apply(); //0 is default value

 if(i == 1){
   mButton.setEnabled(true); 
 }
 else
  mButton.setEnabled(false);
```

I hope this will help. But note that `sharedpreferences` will always remember the state and button will be enabled next time app started until user delete data or reinstall app. I don't know is that what you want but if course it's possible to delete from `sharedpreferences` every time user exits app.